# Accidentally deleted some files

Tags: installation

I accidentally deleted some of files in the installed folder of Mathematica. Is there any way to check the total performance of Mathematica to see if I have introduced problems in the software or not.

Comment: I recommend that you do a reinstall; however, `Needs["Benchmarking\`"]; Benchmark[]` will test many functions.

Comment: Without knowing what files were deleted it would be wild speculation. In any event, I would not bet my job (if I had one) on any result from what is now unknown software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove and reinstall the application.

Comment: Both are possible.  You might not notice anything at all.  Depends on what you deleted.  Obligatory statement:  I would not recommend altering/modifying the contents of $InstallationDirectory.